# Is there a way to update iphone application other than appstore?

Tags: iphone

I need to update my application from a url not from appstore.

Is there a way to do that? Give me suggestions.

Comment: i think this is not possible and this is not the legal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if you are signed up for an apple enterprise developer account. Then you can download and install your apps from a URL that you control. Note you're only allowed to do this for devices used by people in your company.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Is is definitely not possible to update an app downloaded from the app store in this way.